# Ansible > file compare with stat module: Need to check file has the same value or not

Tags: linux, ansible, devops, ansible-2.x, stat

There is a file: **test.txt** on remote1 and remote2 which has version with date and these file contains are n't fixed.

```
$ cat test.txt
Release_P1.11_2017-08-02-094316
02/08/2017
```

I need to check:

> 1. if file contains are same, then move on further tasks.
> 2. if file contains are not same, then stop the tasks.

```
   ---
   - name: latest file check
     stat:
        path: /tmp/test.txt
        get_checksum: yes
     register: test_file_check

   - debug:
        var: test_file_check.stat.checksum
```

Now if file contains are same, checksum value are equal otherwise it doesn't have same. but I don't figure out the solution.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? As is, it looks like "do it for me!"-request

Comment: @techraf I can know the checksum value of file but how to check?

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_conditionals.html

Comment: @techraf I can identify by when condition if it matches. But if file contains are not sure what it will be. so how it will be. I just want to check these files has the same value on two remote hosts

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts

Comment: @techraf I am not sure which magic variables will i use? Could you please tell me

Comment: I could, but I am not going to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is second time check and *when* condition

```
- hosts: remote_1
  tasks:
    - name: first file check
      stat:
        path: /tmp/test.txt
        get_checksum: yes
      register: test_file_check_1

...........................................
- hosts: remote_2
  tasks: 
    - name: next check
      stat:
        path: /tmp/test.txt
        get_checksum: yes
      register: test_file_check_2
...........................................

- name: Block run only if file has no changes
  command: /bin/true
  when: test_file_check_1.stat.checksum == test_file_check_2.stat.checksum
```

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_conditionals.html